# Edge Chromium Favorites -- how to clean up a LOT of them

Tags: microsoft-edge

Here is the only way I see to clean up old faves over the last 11 years ... clearly a housecleaning delay and now it's moving day, LOL.

I have to click the > icon, select one item from the list that I want to delete.  Then delete it and rinse, lather, repeat.  There are a LOT of these.

Clicking the blue star, selecting 'More' and so on, doesn't show this list.

How do I get to where these list items live?  Clearly they're in a file which is accessed when Edge Chromium loads.  Should be able to open it in notepad and do all deletions in minutes.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/998862/edge-favorites-folder-location-on-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manage these bookmarks, you can operate it through the browser. In Edge, you only need to navigate to `edge://favorites/`. It has a clear interface for viewing and managing these bookmarks you saved, and you can select one or more to delete.

In addition, if you want to delete these bookmarks through local files. You can navigate to `edge://version/` to view the path of the bookmark file. Something like this below:
[image]

In this folder path, you will find the `bookmark` file, which saves all the bookmark info saved in Edge.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check each of these out.  Clearly the first option is the way to go.  I was thinking this option wasn't there so the file edit in Notepad would have to be done.

I'll upvote this as soon as I've applied it